# The bookmark level of Bibliograohy and appendices are lower than tha Part level?

Tags: bibliographies, bookmarks, parts, scrreprt

In my thesis, I have divided the contents into two part, which are legible for the readers. I use, for example, `\part{1st Part}` and `\part{2nd Part}` to set their titles. At the end of thesis, I have also added the bibleography and appendices, which is used with `\bibliography{}` and `\begin{appendices}\end{appendices}`, repectively.

The table of contents shows no problem. But the bookmark occurs a small problem. Because the `\part` is shown in ***Part Level***, bibliography and appendices are shown in ***Section Level***, so the bookmarks of bibliography and appendices are included in bookmark of 2nd Part.

Maybe someone can solve this problem, so that the he bookmarks of bibliography and appendices are not included in bookmark of 2nd Part?

The following shows a small template for my problem.

```
\documentclass[english,cd=nocolor]{tudscrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä},germandbls={ß}}

\usepackage[ngerman,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}

% start document
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\title{text}
\maketitle

\TUDoption{abstract}{section,multiple,notoc}

% new command is set to get the correct anchor of abstract in bookmark. The issure will be solved in the new release of tudscrreprt.
\newcommand*\tempheading{}
\begingroup
\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
    \xdef\tempheading{\abstractname/}
\end{otherlanguage}
\xdef\tempheading{\tempheading\abstractname}
\endgroup

\phantomsection\addchaptertocentry{}{\tempheading}
\begin{abstract}[ngerman,pagestyle=plain]
    \blindtext
    \nextabstract[english]
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}

% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents

\cleardoubleemptypage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% content
\chapter{ Introduction }
    \par This is the introduction.
    \section{ Motivation }
        \par This is motivation.
    \section{ Thesis outline }
        \par This is outline.

\part{1st Part}
    \chapter{ 1st chapter of 1st Part }
    \chapter{ 2nd chapter of 1st Part }
\part{2nd Part}
    \chapter{ 1st chapter of 2nd Part }
    \chapter{ 2nd chapter of 2nd Part }

%Bibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} %Durchnummeriert
\bibliography{reference}

%Appendices
\begin{appendices}
    This is the appendices
\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

The table of content looks like normal(but also not right, because there is no break line between **5. 2nd chapter of 2nd Part** and **Bibliography**)

[image].

the bookmark is shown like

[image].

Thanks in advance.

Xiaodi

Comment: `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` before the bibliography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
```

before `\bibliography`.

Additional remark: Use option `bibliography=totoc` to add an ToC entry for the bibliography. Do not add the entry manually.

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{example-bib.bib}
@book{aristotle:physics, 
  author       = {Aristotle}, 
  title        = {Physics}, 
  date         = 1929, 
  translator   = {Wicksteed, P. H. and Cornford, F. M.}, 
  publisher    = {G. P. Putnam}, 
  shorttitle   = {Physics}, 
} 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[english,cd=nocolor,
  bibliography=totoc% <- added
]{tudscrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä},germandbls={ß}}

\usepackage[ngerman,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}

% start document
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\title{text}
\maketitle

\TUDoption{abstract}{section,multiple,notoc}

%new command is set to get the correct anchor of abstract in bookmark. The issure will be solved in the new release of tudscrreprt.
\cleardoublepage
\newcommand*\tempheading{}
\begingroup
\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
    \xdef\tempheading{\abstractname/}
\end{otherlanguage}
\xdef\tempheading{\tempheading\abstractname}
\endgroup
\phantomsection\addchaptertocentry{}{\tempheading}
\begin{abstract}[ngerman,pagestyle=plain]
    \blindtext
    \nextabstract[english]
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents
\cleardoubleemptypage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
% content
\chapter{ Introduction }
    \par This is the introduction.
    \section{ Motivation }
        \par This is motivation.
    \section{ Thesis outline }
        \par This is outline.
\part{1st Part}
    \chapter{ 1st chapter of 1st Part }
    \chapter{ 2nd chapter of 1st Part }
\part{2nd Part}
    \chapter{ 1st chapter of 2nd Part }
    \chapter{ 2nd chapter of 2nd Part }
%Bibliography
\nocite{aristotle:physics}
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}% <- added
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} %Durchnummeriert
\bibliography{example-bib}
%Appendices
\begin{appendices}
    This is the appendices
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```